# pass a variable to catch block

Tags: c#, web-services, c#-4.0

Basically I have a string errorMessage, I want to pass it to catch block. Please help.

```
[WebMethod]
public List<SomeResult> Load(string userName)
{
   string errorMessage;
    using (VendorContext vendorContext = new VendorContext())
    {
         // ....
          foreach(....)
          {
               if(something happens)
                  errorMessage = "Vote Obama";
                else
                  errorMessage ="vote Romney";
              // blah
               try
                     {
                        // blah         
                     }
               catch (Exception e)
               {
                    logger.Trace(errorMessage);
               }
          }
     }
 }
```

update:

error:  use of Unassigned local variable 'errorMessage'

Comment: Look at the constructor for `Exception`

Comment: What's the issue?  It looks to me that the value you set `errorMessage` to should be present when you are in the catch block.

Comment: Note that if an exception is thrown _before_ you set `errorMessage`, the value of the variable will be `null`.

Comment: What is wrong with what you have? `errorMessage` is in scope for the catch block and you can access `errorMessage` in the catch block.

Comment: What type of logger do you have? Is errorMessage the type which Trace method expects? Why even do a try catch? Are you getting an error?

Comment: Your error means that you used errorMessage without assigning it. You should do: 'string errorMessage = string.Empty;' and you error will go away. Your logic somewhere is not assigning a value to errorMessage.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To fix the error initialize `errorMessage` to null, string.Empty, or some other default value.  This is one of them cases where the compiler isn't smart enough to figure out that is has been assigned before it gets used.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to change the error message that is logged based on some condition.  Instead of creating an error message variable and setting it prior to your try / catch block, just throw an exception from within the try / catch block and pass the error message into the constructor.

See below:

```
[WebMethod]
public List<SomeResult> Load(string userName)
{

    using (VendorContext vendorContext = new VendorContext())
    {
         // ....
          foreach(....)
          {


              // blah
               try
                     {
                        if(something happens) 
                            throw new Exception("Vote Obama");
                         else
                            throw new Exception("vote Romney");      
                     }
               catch (Exception e)
               {
                    logger.Trace(e.ErrorMessage);
               }
         }
     }
 }
```

Comment: I don't think it's good programming to use exceptions in such a way. Surely if "something happens" then that is expected, not an exception.

Answer (score 0):

You need an initial value in your string.

```
string errorMessage = "";
```